# How to enable binlog on aurora serverless

Tags: aws-aurora-serverless

I am setting up a new database using AWS Aurora serverless and have a requirement to enable binlog. I think I have followed the documentation as-is but can't get it to work. How do I set it up?

Following the documentation, below is what I have tried to enable binlog.

- Created a custom Parameter Group of type as "DB cluster parameter group" and Family as Aurora5.6.
- Changed binlog_format parameter to ROW for the parameter Group.
- Created a new database with Role as serverless and Engine as "Aurora MySQL" and assigned parameter group created above.
- Enabled backup retention to 3 days (enabled this as I saw some posts somewhere that unless you enable backups binlog doesn't really get enabled).
- I have also tried to modify the DB and apply/force the parameter group by selecting "apply Immediately".

I expect the binlog is enabled after database goes from modifying to available state and I should be able to see the Global variable on the DB correctly set.

I see following -

mysql> select variable_value from information_schema.global_variables where variable_name='log_bin';

+----------------+
| variable_value |
+----------------+
| OFF            |
+----------------+

1 row in set (0.01 sec)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The serverless version of Aurora only gives you a subset of parameters that you can change - see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless.parameter-groups, and of course turning on binlogging is not available.  So if you need your Aurora DB to act as a Master then don't use serverless!

Comment: Thanks Stuart! Solved this sometime back by going to Aurora RDS.